# how can I reload an onscroll function after refresh

Tags: jquery, page-refresh, onscroll

my header changes from color on scroll. But when I refresh the page, it goes back to its first color. How can I refresh a page without effecting de jQuery?

**jQuery**

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var start_scroll = 0,
      start_change = $('#change-it-now'),
      offset = start_change.offset();

    if (start_change.length) {
      $(document).scroll(function() {
        start_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (start_scroll > offset.top) {
          $('nav').css('background-color', '#646464');
        } else {
          $('nav').css('background-color', '  #2b2b2b');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x9ncbtw0/

Comment: There is a problem about your approach.. Javascript/Jquery is client-sided.

Page refresh is a new load from the server. So it is server-sided. You would have to store the current navigation color somewhere on the server or in a server-variable to be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the color in `localStorage`,

1. When you change the `nav` bg, store it in `localStorage`.
2. On page loading, check if a color stored in `localStorage` and if so, update it.

Something like:

```js
var lastBg = localStorage.getItem('color');
if (lastBg) {
  $('nav').css('background', lastBg);
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
    localStorage.setItem('color', 'red');
    $('nav').css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

http://output.jsbin.com/fimiceg/3

Comment: Thanks! It works a kind of... The only problem that remains now is that the header gets the old color again when I scroll up.

Comment: I pasted my new code under the old one so that you can see how I've processed it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. Is your problem resolved?

Comment: Yes my problem is solved, but there another problem now. see: http://eduweb.hhs.nl/~17012988/portfolioverslag/ . 
If you scroll down (all the way to the bottom) the header will change color nicely, but when you scroll back to the top you immediately get the default color

Comment: A. If it answer your question, please accept it so it will help to other people. B. About your question, sure it's back to the default background, you are doing this in the `else` part of the `checkScroll` function.

Comment: @StijnSlats is that answer your question?

Comment: And where should it be than?

Comment: Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172034/how-can-i-reload-an-onscroll-function-after-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Chrome will remember your scroll position on refresh, so it might be good to just set the color inside a function and call that function on scroll. Then, you can call the same function on page load, with the current scrollTop, and it should set the color right.

Something like this:

```
var start_change;

$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    start_change = $('#change-it-now');
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if (start_change.length) {
            checkScroll($(this).scrollTop());
        }
    });
  });

  checkScroll($(document).scrollTop());

});

function checkScroll(start_scroll) {
    var start_scroll = 0,
      offset = start_change.offset();
    if (start_scroll > offset.top) {
      $('nav').css('background-color', '#646464');
    } else {
      $('nav').css('background-color', '  #2b2b2b');
    }
}
```